# ExtJS override css properties

Tags: css, extjs

I am using ExtJS textarea and trying to remove the border and background image for the textarea. I am able to remove the border for the textarea, but unable to remove the default background-image.

The component in fact is not taking the background I have set in fieldStyle. When I inspect the element in firebug after the textarea is rendered, I don't see the background in the style.

```
var textArea=Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
       width:200,
       fieldStyle:'border:none;background:#FFF !important;width:120px;'
}
```

How do I override the background and width only for the field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, besides adding the "!important" directive, your stylesheet must be the last one to be loaded, the "cascading concept", so your rule would be the one to be read.

after the CSS rules loaded for extjs, yours must come after.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

change to `background-color:#FFF !important`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but still the property is not being picked up by ExtJS